# define pattern of re.compile by interactive method

Tags: python

I am new to python programming, please let me know what changes need to done if I need to input integer 2468 to compile pattern as user interactive mode.

Code:

```
f = open ('C:\\Users\\anash\\Desktop\\SIP Success call.txt')
file = f.read()

import re
regex1 = re.compile(r'INVITE sip:.*?**2468**.*?Content-Length: \d+',re.DOTALL)

filtfile = regex1.findall(file)
print (filtfile[0])
```

Comment: I need program to look like:

Print ('enter the last four digits')
LastFourDigit = input()
************
then I need add this digits to the compile pattern

Answer (score 0):

In the interactive shell, enter the following:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex1 = re.compile(r'INVITE sip:.*?**2468**.*?Content-Length: \d+',re.DOTALL)
>>> filtfile = regex1.findall("Any input you want to enter")
>>> print(filtfile[0])
```

Comment: Giving me an error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Anas It will, if there's no match.

Comment: # Program to pull the paragraph which contain a certain pattern ('INVITE sip:.*?2468.*?Content-Length: \d+')
# 2468 mentioned in the re.compile is variable, so user need to define this four digit

Comment: @Anas Please be more articulate.

Comment: This program is to pull a paragraph which starts with "INVITE sip" and should contain specific four digit number and ends with " Content-Length: 1" , and user need to enter this four digit number on prompt.

Comment: @Anas Have you tried using `input()` or `raw_input()`?